# Open mobile camera from browser

Tags: android, html, ios, camera, media

I have a web app that l'et select any camera connected on a PC. I cannot let this choice on mobile.
Is there a way tò collect all the camera presents or let the native app to Jump in and give the Pic back?

I made any kind of try by getmedia but without a good result

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With HTML5 came the introduction of APIs with access to device hardware, including the `MediaDevices` API. You can use this API’s to access audio and video devices to stream and display live video feeds in the browser.

Please refer this documentation for more information:
[MediaStream Recording API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API)

If you want to get all the available camera/media information then please refer this documentation for more information:
[MediaDevices Enumerate All Devices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices)